# How to compile this function to speed up operation?

Tags: compile, ccompilerdriver, function-compile

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
five[n_] := 
 Module[{v = 
    SparseArray[LowerTriangularize[Outer[Plus, #, #] &[Range[n]^4]]][
     "NonzeroValues"], t, k, x55, a, b, s, x1, x2, x3, x4}, 
  k = Ordering@v;
  t = v[[k]];
  Monitor[Do[x55 = x5^4; a = 1;
    Do[s = x55 - t[[b]]; While[t[[a]] < s, ++a];
     If[t[[a]] == s, x2 = Round[Sqrt[2 k[[a]]]];
      x1 = k[[a]] - x2 (x2 - 1)/2; x4 = Round[Sqrt[2 k[[b]]]];
      x3 = k[[b]] - x4 (x4 - 1)/2;
      If[x2 <= x3 || x4 <= x1, Print@{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]], {b, 
      Ceiling@BinarySearch[t, x55/2], 1, -1}], {x5, 2, n}], 
   Row[{ProgressIndicator[x5, {2, n}], x5}, " "]]
  ]
(*in:five[353]
out:res = {272, 315, 30, 120, 353}
res[[1]]^4 + res[[2]]^4 + res[[3]]^4 + res[[4]]^4 - res[[5]]^4==0*)
```

The C language environment is already configured. I have tried the following code:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw64\\bin", 
   "CompilerName" -> "gcc.exe"};
five = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Module[{v = 
     SparseArray[LowerTriangularize[Outer[Plus, #, #] &[Range[n]^4]]][
      "NonzeroValues"], t, k, x55, a, b, s, x1, x2, x3, x4}, 
   k = Ordering@v;
   t = v[[k]];
   Monitor[Do[x55 = x5^4; a = 1;
     Do[s = x55 - t[[b]]; While[t[[a]] < s, ++a];
      If[t[[a]] == s, x2 = Round[Sqrt[2 k[[a]]]];
       x1 = k[[a]] - x2 (x2 - 1)/2; x4 = Round[Sqrt[2 k[[b]]]];
       x3 = k[[b]] - x4 (x4 - 1)/2;
       If[x2 <= x3 || x4 <= x1, Print@{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]], {b, 
       Ceiling@BinarySearch[t, x55/2], 1, -1}], {x5, 2, n}], 
    Row[{ProgressIndicator[x5, {2, n}], x5}, " "]]
   ],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

[image: warning]
It seems to have failed, and there has been no significant improvement in speed.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is original by @flc:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw64\\bin", 
   "CompilerName" -> "gcc.exe"};
cf = With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, 
   Compile[{{v, _Integer, 1}, {k, _Integer, 1}, {x5, _Integer}}, 
    Module[{x55 = x5^4, a = 1, l = 1, r = Length@v + 1, m, t, x, x1, 
      x2, x3, x4}, x = BitShiftRight[x55, 1] + 1;
     While[l + 1 < r, m = BitShiftRight[l + r, 1];
      If[g[v, m] < x, l = m, r = m]];
     Do[t = x55 - g[v, b]; While[g[v, a] < t, ++a];
      If[g[v, a] == 
        t, {x2, x4} = {Round[Sqrt[2 g[k, a]]], 
         Round[Sqrt[2 g[k, b]]]}; {x1, 
         x3} = {g[k, a] - BitShiftRight[x2 (x2 - 1), 1], 
         g[k, b] - BitShiftRight[x4 (x4 - 1), 1]};
       If[x2 <= x3 || x4 <= x1, Print@{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]], {b, l, 
       1, -1}]], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
five[n_] := 
 Module[{v = 
    SparseArray[LowerTriangularize[Outer[Plus, #, #] &[Range[n]^4]]][
     "NonzeroValues"], k}, k = Ordering@v; v = v[[k]];
  Monitor[Do[cf[v, k, x5], {x5, 2, n}], 
   Row[{ProgressIndicator[x5, {2, n}], x5}, " "]]]
```

It is indeed much faster than the uncompiled version.

Comment: Another Writing Method for Assigning Values to v : ```v = Reverse@GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[Range[n, 1, -1], 2]^4 . {1, 1}```